# How to call JavaScript in XML?

Tags: javascript, python, xml, sass, odoo-9

We struck it one point. That is,
We created a demo module, inside that we created manifest files, views, models and static folders.
Inside static

```
--source folder,
--javascript folder,
--CSS folder
```

Inside views: We created a new XML file and created a template and called java script file inside that template.
We followed above producer.

1. How to check our JavaScript, whether it is running in our browser or
   not? In which page that is reflecting? How to find that?
2. And how to override calendar in our java script and call that in XML?
3. What is the purpose of using q web? Should we use it for re-designing calendar?

Comment: why you have tagged openerp

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/qweb.html):

> QWeb is the primary templating engine used by Odoo. It is an XML
>   templating engine1 and used mostly to generate HTML fragments and
>   pages.
>
> Although it uses a few others, either for historical reasons or
>   because they remain better fits for the use case. Odoo 8.0 still
>   depends on Jinja and Mako

If you are creating or modifying a template (i.e.: calendar template), you can write JavaScript code directly. You can use HTML code as well.

If you are modifying or creating a new view or report you are more limited. But I think you won't need to run JavaScript in these environments. If you need it you can [build a widget](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html#widgets-basics) as well.